# remove whitespaces and commas when reading from a file in python

Tags: python, regex, graph-theory

I have to build a graph from a file that has the following structure :

```
1   80,982  163,8164    170,2620    145,648 200,8021    173,2069
```

The first digit is the vertex (`1`) and `80` is the adjacent vertex with the weight `982`. I want to strip the line out of spaces and that comma.

I tried with `strip()` and `split(',')` but i can't find a suitable format to build my graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the structure of your data correctly, that each line contains one vertex and pairs of its adjacent vertices and weights, you can do this by only using `split` as follows:

```
lines = "1 80,982 163,8164 170,2620 145,648 200,8021 173,2069"
graph = {}
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    vertex, *neighbors = line.split()
    graph[vertex] = [tuple(neighbor.split(','))
                     for neighbor in neighbors]
```

The result is a dictionary that contains the vertices as keys and a list of the adjacent vertices–weights tuples as values.

Answer (score 4):

you can process your task using regex easily as below:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "1 80,982 163,8164 170,2620 145,648 200,8021 173,2069"
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+) (\d+),(\d+)', s) # pass your file content s as string
[('1', '80', '982'), ('8164', '170', '2620'), ('648', '200', '8021')]
```

Explanation:

`findall` - returns list of all matched pattern

`\d+` - match one or more digits